# JAXB is always returning the last <test> tag when there should not be more than 1 <test> tag

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

1. The user provides an XML file with a specific schema
2. The class I have takes the XML file and converts it to a Model (DataFile.class)
3. The DataFile model is passed onto the next classes for validation and inseration into the database (this part is not relevant for my issue)

The Structure of the XML is as such:

```
<xml .../>
<dataFile>
    <header>
        <name>firstname</name>
        <name>surname</name>
    </header>
    <content>
        <row>
            <column>seb</column>
            <column>teb</column>
        </row>
        <row>
            <column>leb</column>
            <column>pleb</column>
        </row>
    </content>
</dataFile>
```

The schema is quite farfetched, please don't get triggered.

Now this is my model, which consists of 4 classes,

DataFile.class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class DataFile {

    private Header header;
    private Content content;

    public DataFile() {
        this.header = new Header();
        this.content = new Content();
    }

    public DataFile(Header header, Content content) {
        this.header = header;
        this.content = content;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Header getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(Header header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Content getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(Content content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

Header.class

```
public class Header {

    private List<String> name;

    public Header() {
        this.name = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Header(List<String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(List<String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Content.class

```
public class Content {

    private List<Row> row;

    public Content() {
        this.row = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Content(List<Row> rows) {
        this.row = rows;
    }

    public List<Row> getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public void setRow(List<Row> row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

}
```

Row.class

```
public class Row {

    private List<String> column;

    public Row() {

    }

    public Row(List<String> column) {
        this.column = column;
    }

    public List<String> getColumn() {
        return column;
    }

    public void setColumn(List<String> column) {
        this.column = column;
    }

}
```

This is the method i use to unmarshal the XML file to the DataFile model:

```
public DataFile JaxBValidate(File file) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataFile.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    return (DataFile) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
}
```

The issue I have is that, if I have more than 1  tags, JAXB will always pick up the last one, where i want it to throw an exception if there are more than 1 headers.

I have looked around and found nothing on this, i have also looked at the anotations for the DataFile model and i have not found anything to specify that i only want to have 1 header tag.

I have found a solution to use XPath for the parsing instead of using the JAXB, but i am curious if someone else may know something about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `XSD` file where number of fields is set and attach it to `JAXB` unmarshaller:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="dataFile" type="dataFileType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="headerType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="rowType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="column" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="contentType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="rowType" name="row" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="dataFileType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="headerType" name="header" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element type="contentType" name="content" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And this is how we can unmarshal `XML` with schema:

```
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JaxbApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File xmlFile = new File("./resource/test.xml").getAbsoluteFile();
        File xsdFile = new File("./resource/test.xsd").getAbsoluteFile();

        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(xsdFile);

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataFile.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);

        Object root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
        System.out.println(root);
    }
}
```

For below `XML` payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataFile>
    <header>
        <name>firstname</name>
        <name>surname</name>
    </header>
    <header>
        <name>firstname1</name>
        <name>surname1</name>
    </header>
    <content>
        <row>
            <column>seb</column>
            <column>teb</column>
        </row>
        <row>
            <column>leb</column>
            <column>pleb</column>
        </row>
    </content>
</dataFile>
```

Throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:./resource/test.xml; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 13; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'header'. One of '{content}' is expected.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:563)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
```

See also:

- [JAXB and Marshal/Unmarshal Schema Validation](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html)

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was something that i was missing out, just couldn't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 0):

try with this,

DataFile.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class DataFile {

    private List<Header> header;
    private List<Content> content;

    @XmlElement
    public List<Header> getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(List<Header> header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public List<Content> getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(List<Content> content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Header.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Header {

    private List<String> name;

    @XmlElement
    public List<String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(List<String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Content.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Content {

    private List<Row> row;

    @XmlElement
    public List<Row> getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public void setRow(List<Row> row) {
        this.row = row;
    }
}
```

Row.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Row {

    private List<String> column;

    @XmlElement
    public List<String> getColumn() {
        return column;
    }

    public void setColumn(List<String> column) {
        this.column = column;
    }
}
```

for DataFile unmarshalling

```
File file = new File("xmlFile.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataFile.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
DataFile dataFile = (DataFile) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

for get the number of `<header>` tags in given xml file

```
int noOfHeader = dataFile.getHeader().size();
```

Comment: yes, that would work, however that is a workaround in order to get all the <header></header> tags and check if there are more than 1, however, my issue is that i didn't specify the header variable in the DataFile model as a list of headers, i specified it as a single object, the weird thing is that it should not retrieve the last, should throw an error or something, what i want to know is if it's normal behaviour for jaxb of if it just doesn't cover this scenario